# regular expression for attributes of a dictionary

Tags: python, regex

I have an XML snippet like:

```
<CharacterBlock MinVal="-10.000000"  MaxVal="15.000000" Active="1">
```

and I need to parse the minimum and maximum floating point values. I can't use an XML parser like ElementTree, so I'm forced to use a regular expression.

I have written the following Python regex:

```
re.compile('<CharacterBlock MinVal="(?P<MinVal>-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)" MaxVal="(?P<MaxVal>-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)" .*?>', re.DOTALL)
```

which works for the above snippet. But since the XML attributes are like a dictionary, their order is not guaranteed, and sometimes I receive a snippet like:

```
<CharacterBlock Active="0" MaxVal="-15.000000" MinVal="-100.000000">
```

How do I handle this case where the order of the groups I want to match is not fixed?

Comment: Like I said in my question, due to the constrains of the environment I'm working in, I can't use an XML parser and am forced to use a regex.

Comment: Use one *anyway.* If there's not one installed, you can install one next to your script (or even include it in your script if you can only have a single file for some reason). If a DOM parser uses too much memory, use a SAX parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you get the two values separately ? like:

```
In [2]: s='<CharacterBlock Active="0" MaxVal="-15.000000" MinVal="-100.000000">'
In [3]: import re
In [4]: manReg='(?<=MaxVal=")[^"]*'
In [5]: minReg='(?<=MinVal=")[^"]*'

In [6]: re.findall(minReg, s)
Out[7]: ['-100.000000']

In [8]: re.findall(maxReg, s)
Out[9]: ['-15.000000']
```

Answer (score 1):

As the order is not fixed and there are other fields, it seems your best bet is to use two regular expressions, one for MaxVal and the other one for MinVal.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
for xmltag in re.finditer(r'<CharacterBlock.*?>', s):
    ismin = re.search(r'\bMinVal=["\'](.*?)[\'"]', xmltag.group(0))
    if ismin:
        min=ismin.group(1)
    ismax= re.search(r'\bMaxVal=["\'](.*?)[\'"]', xmltag.group(0))
    if ismax:
        max=ismax.group(1)
    if ismin and ismax:
        print "Min: %s,  Max %s" % (min, max)
```